i keep getting this error : TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead
i am trying to train mobilevit using this bee dataset from tensorflow and i keep getting this error
TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead.
this is the code i wrote, everything works except this piece of code, is the problem with the dataset ?
train_dataset, val_dataset = tfds.load(
    "bee_dataset/bee_dataset_300", split=["train[:90%]", "train[90%:]"], as_supervised=True
)

num_train = train_dataset.cardinality()
num_val = val_dataset.cardinality()
print(f"Number of training examples: {num_train}")
print(f"Number of validation examples: {num_val}")

train_dataset = prepare_dataset(train_dataset, is_training=True)
val_dataset = prepare_dataset(val_dataset, is_training=False)

i tried another dataset and it worked just fine but the error persists for this one

What line of code is throwing error?

this one "train_dataset = prepare_dataset(train_dataset, is_training=True)"

Is that your function or did you import it from somewhere?

its from the tensorflow site ,and found the same thing in multiple documentations ,it works on other datasets but gives this error with the bee dataset from tensorflow

Can you please share link to docs for that function. Can't seem to find it.

Hi inter galactic, The error shows that there is a problem with the data type.Check that you are using the correct format (input, label)and also sometimes, dataset splits may return wrong results. To verify the splits are correct, check the first few records from both the training and validation datasets.
